# MySQL: select and divide by count using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's a data set of my table

```
ID  |groupID|   Start   | End   | SegStart  | SegEnd    | something
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   1   |   0.234   | 0.345 |   0.345   |   0.677   | 0
2   |   1   |   0.234   | 0.345 |   0.346   |   0.678   | 0
3   |   1   |   0.234   | 0.345 |   0.347   |   0.679   | 0
4   |   1   |   0.234   | 0.345 |   0.348   |   0.680   | 1
5   |   2   |   0.345   | 0.567 |   0.568   |   0.570   | 0
6   |   2   |   0.345   | 0.567 |   0.569   |   0.571   | 1
7   |   3   |   0.567   | 0.678 |   0.679   |   0.681   | 0
8   |   3   |   0.567   | 0.678 |   0.680   |   0.682   | 0
9   |   3   |   0.567   | 0.678 |   0.681   |   0.683   | 1
```

I want to calculate a value from the Start / End columns as well as the SegStart / SegEnd columns where something = "1" and then divide this value by the number of items in a group (group 1 has 4 items, group 2 has 2, group 3 has 3, etc)

I've tried this query, but it gives me the error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

```
select (((End - Start) - (SegEnd - SegStart)) / 
  (select count(*) as NumSeg from table group by groupID)) as NewValue 
from table where something = "1";
```

I would like a list of the new value for each group, kind of like this (values are imaginary):

```
groupID |   NewValue
--------------------
1       |   0.102
2       |   0.110   
3       |   0.036
```

Comment: Remve the GROUP BY from the sub-query, add  a WHERE instead.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I would like to have a list of NewValue per group

Comment: Edit your question and add the expected result as a table, well formatted. (Like your sample data.)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query
... and note that `group` is a reserved word, rendering it a poor choice for a column identifier.

Comment: If you just want imaginary values, RAND() will suffice.

Comment: I did not have the time to calculate actual values, thus the imaginary ones. Naturally I would like the actual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ID        INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,groupID   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Start     NUMERIC(11,3) NOT NULL
  ,End       NUMERIC(7,3) NOT NULL
  ,SegStart  NUMERIC(11,3) NOT NULL
  ,SegEnd    NUMERIC(11,3) NOT NULL
  ,something BIT  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,groupID,Start,End,SegStart,SegEnd,something) VALUES (1,1,0.234,0.345,0.345,0.677,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,groupID,Start,End,SegStart,SegEnd,something) VALUES (2,1,0.234,0.345,0.346,0.678,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,groupID,Start,End,SegStart,SegEnd,something) VALUES (3,1,0.234,0.345,0.347,0.679,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,groupID,Start,End,SegStart,SegEnd,something) VALUES (4,1,0.234,0.345,0.348,0.680,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,groupID,Start,End,SegStart,SegEnd,something) VALUES (5,2,0.345,0.567,0.568,0.570,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,groupID,Start,End,SegStart,SegEnd,something) VALUES (6,2,0.345,0.567,0.569,0.571,1);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,groupID,Start,End,SegStart,SegEnd,something) VALUES (7,3,0.567,0.678,0.679,0.681,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,groupID,Start,End,SegStart,SegEnd,something) VALUES (8,3,0.567,0.678,0.680,0.682,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,groupID,Start,End,SegStart,SegEnd,something) VALUES (9,3,0.567,0.678,0.681,0.683,1);


select A.GROUPID, ((End - Start) - (SegEnd - SegStart)) / B.NumSeg AS V1
from mytable A
INNER JOIN  (select GROUPID, count(*) as NumSeg from mytable group by GROUPID) B ON A.GROUPID = B.GROUPID
where something = "1";
```

Output:

```
    GROUPID V1
1   1   -0,0552500
2   2   0,1100000
3   3   0,0363333
```

Comment: Gives me 0 results, unfortunately :/

Comment: Give me a minute, it should be only a problem of conversion

Comment: It works for me (see edited answer).  Can you post columns datatype?

Comment: still not for me... ID & groupID are INT, all others are VARCHAR.

Comment: I tried modifing start, end, segstart and segend as varchar, but it still works for me... Can you try my whole script please and verify results?  Can you post script you run and results?

Comment: Works now, I went over it 5 times until I realized that I made a mistake in the where condition xD